# Failing tests -> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rpc')

Tags: javascript, typescript, blockchain, smartcontracts, solana

I was writing a test in TypeScript for Adding two numbers. I am receiving the following error:

```
Adds two numbers:
     TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rpc')
      at Context.<anonymous> (tests/calculator.ts:33:19)
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at /mnt/e/solana/calculator/tests/calculator.ts:7:71
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at __awaiter (tests/calculator.ts:3:12)
      at Context.<anonymous> (tests/calculator.ts:35:16)
      at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:473:21)
```

Following is the code:

```js
const Anchor = require('@project-serum/anchor');

describe('calculator',() => {

    const provider = Anchor.Provider.local();
    Anchor.setProvider(provider);
    
    const calculator = Anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
    const program = Anchor.workspace.calculator;
    var _calculator;
it('Creates a calculator', async() => {
        await program.rpc.create("Welcome to My calculator",{
            accounts: {
                calculator: calculator.publicKey,
                user: provider.wallet.publicKey,
                SystemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
            },
            signers: [calculator]
        });
        const account = await 
        program.account.calculator.fetch(calculator.publicKey);
        assert.ok(account.greeting === "Welcome to My calculator");
        _calculator = calculator;
    });
```

This is working on Solana blockchain using anchor-cli. Can someone help?

Comment: Which doc do you use ? I didn't find "calculator" from object "workspace" : https://github.com/project-serum/anchor/blob/44b66c5e8428481b5885e6d65473956fbf6dd48f/ts/src/workspace.ts
So your object "program" is undefined

Answer (score 2):

`program` is undefined. That means this line of code has issue

```
 const program = Anchor.workspace.calculator;
```

Anchor capitalizes the contract name. so it should be "Calculator"

```
 const program = Anchor.workspace.Calculator;
```

Answer (score 0):

import AnchorProvider from @project-serum/anchor and assign provider to it instead, like:

```js
const provider = AnchorProvider.local()
```

I think this should solve the problem. If you have an error with systemProgram, import web3 from anchor in a similar manner.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this `../target/types/calculator` directory and make sure it exports like

```
export type Calculator = {
```

any change of type will make it fail to define `program`